# Capacitor question - energy from pushing a baby stroller

Tags: electrical, supercapacitor

[image]

I’m making a circuit that will be added to a stroller.  With a 24 volt DC motor, I’m trying to power the capacitor by walking around & simulating a baby/mother experience and if I run into a hill or steep slope, I should be able to turn on the switch and with all the energy that I have stored throughout the day, it should able to power the second motor, which will assist with the work necessary to climb the hill with the stroller.

This is the diagram for that, so the two volt LED was just a test to simulate since I was only obtaining low voltages since the voltage was in a parallel configuration, just wondering if there could be a way to avoid that configuration so that the capacitor can collectively power the motor instead of providing the same voltage.

As for the diagram:

I have a switch on the far right closed & a switch in the middle open so that the capacitors will have a connection straight to the motor and charge when the other switch is open, then I’ll reverse the set up when I need to turn on the light, be turning off the switch on the far right and turning on the switch in the middle.

My issue is that the capacitors still don’t combine voltages, I have 0.7 volts for all three capacitors, so the 2 volt LED should be turning on in this configuration, but the voltage on the LED is the exact same as the capacitors, 0.7 volts,.

Any ideas?

Comment: A suggestion:  Calculate the energy required to move a stroller (plus baby and other accessories) up a hill.  Compare that to the total energy your capacitors can store - and realize that you can pretty much **never*" get all of the stored energy back.  I think you will be disappointed by the amount of assistance your system  can provide.

Comment: That is a good point, but so far all I’m currently trying to do is use an 2V LED to atleast get a baseline for this experiment, so I have all three of the capacitors in parallel, equal to 0.7V so with there combined voltage, I just wanted to turn on the light, so that even if the capacitors don’t provide significant power, atleast the theory can be played with from there; however I can’t get the LED to have anything but 0.7V or whatever the capacitor voltages are, so I’m just confused what I can do to atleast accomplish that aspect. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can, I think, be stated thus:

> I want to harvest energy from a baby stroller motor while it is being pushed on the level or downhill and store the energy in a bank of capacitors. On reaching a hill I want to use the stored energy to drive the motor to assist with propelling the stroller.

The normal practice here would be to use the motor as both motor and generator. The voltage you'll get out of the generator at a certain speed will be a bit less than the voltage that will drive the motor at that speed.
For example, if 10 V causes the motor to drive the stroller at 2 m/s then pushing the stroller at 2 m/s might generate about 9 V. It will also act as a brake on the stroller so it will be harder to push.

Next steps:

- Turn your motor at the speed you think it will run at in normal walking.
- Measure the output voltage.
- If you can, apply that voltage to the motor and confirm that it runs close to the same speed as discussed above.
- Measure the current drawn. You'll need that to work out how much energy you need to store in the capacitors.
- Post the results in your question and we'll go from there.

> My issue is that the capacitors still don’t combine voltages, I have 0.7 volts for all three capacitors, so the 2 volt LED should be turning on in this configuration, but the voltage on the LED is the exact same as the capacitors, 0.7 volts.

Your capacitors are in parallel when you charge them and are in parallel when you're trying to use them so the voltage is still 0.7 V.

Comment: I can’t use the space the same as a computer so sorry if this looks alittle sloppy. 1) I turned it at 100 rpm. 2) The voltage on the motor fluctuated around 1.7-2.0 V. 3) I only have a 9-volt battery, and it ends up being less than 100 rpm so I’m not sure if that would be suitable.  4) the current on the motor fluctuated from 2.5mA to 3.5mA.

Comment: 1) OK. That's probably a small fraction of the rated speed. 2) 2 V will be useless. You won't be able to do anything in this application with only 2 V. 3) I would have expected > 300 RPM from 9 V but the battery may not be strong enough. 4) 3.5 mA seems tiny for a motor to propel a stroller. You need to measure the current needed under load.

Comment: So most likely an actual assembly will be better off than a prototype, or a larger battery to produce a larger RPM. I understand, and hold on, if the capacitor only works in parallel when it’s in that configuration, is there anyway to have the voltage of each capacitor add up to power a load?

Comment: You're out of your depth here and need to learn a lot about motors, power, energy and battery storage. There are thousands of articles online. I'm sorry but this site is for specific electrical engineering questions rather than broad educational answers.